# Where are profile2 fields shown?

Tags: users

I have installed the profile2 module and added some fields, but I can't find where are they shown. How do I display fields' values for a user?

I also can't change fields' values after creating a user.Fields are shown only in user registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default admin theme you should see a tab on each user edit page for each profile type in the top right hand corner, e.g.

[image]

You should also see a tab on the user page itself for each profile type, the fields are displayed in there.